# Suggestions for implementing "inverse document frequency" on GAE?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, tf-idf

I need to implement "inverse document frequency" in Google app engine. I'm looking for suggestions to improve efficiency. Now I take the basic routine as,

when parsing a webpage I save each  pair to datastore, like,

```
for(String phrase : phrase_collection){
  dataStore.put(phrase, domain);
}
```

when computing the IDF later I fetch the occurrence of the phrase from datastore, like,

```
for(String phrase : phrase_collection){
  long count = dataStore.get(phrase).size();
}
```

However the speed is not satisfying and results in 30sec timeout often. In this scenario I have additional challenges,

-Multi language input(webpages). So the phrases are also in different languages, which makes it hard to cache.

-Parsing webpages and ranking phrases take much time as well. The whole process is like charset_detect -> language_detect -> parse according to different languages -> ranking.

Always on enabled in GAE.

I'm looking forward to any suggestions! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing an individual get (and put) for each phrase. This is naturally going to be very slow, as you're doing a great many roundtrips to the datastore. Instead, you should use the variants of [put](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService.html#put%28java.lang.Iterable%29) and [get](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService.html#get%28java.lang.Iterable%29) that accept an iterable of entities or keys, and execute them all in a single transaction.

You should also do this work 'offline' - as Stefan suggests, using backends or task queues. Task queues would likely be a better match here.

Comment: Batch get/put is an essential idea however hard to assemble the Query criteria. Besides, I cannot do this offline since I need to rank phrases P (from the same document) against the document in realtime. I'm trying with Cache and AsyncDataStore and it feels better.

Comment: @Shuai I'm not sure I understand your comment. Query criteria don't apply to a batch get or put, and you _do_ need to batch operations here - it should be easy, too.

Comment: I meant 1) it's difficult to retrieve all phrases from datastore and store in memcache, esp. the storage keeps growing rapidly in all languages. 2) then for each document I have to retrieve phrases appeared in it instead of all. In this case how can you batch get?

Comment: @Shuai Memcache has batch operations, the same as the datastore. To get records for the phrases that appear in the document, simply accumulate a list of key objects, one per phrase, and do a single `datastore.get` on the list. It'll return a list of objects.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

You could use the newly introduced backends to get things up and running. That way you don't have to deal with the timeout and don't have to worry about parallel tasks.

You could use the task queue. (As an alternative to the backend.) But that depends on your ability to parallize your tasks.

And in any case, you should start using memcache. (If you use JDO you can simply enable it [like so](http://ukena.de/content/enabling-jdo-caching-google-app-engine)). You could also consider switching to a "more native" persistence layer like objectify or twig, which support asyn access and/or memcache out of the box.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try backends first.